# Cannot start mongodb in Mac

Tags: mongodb

In my mac 11.5.2, I wanted to install mongodb. I tried to install by `brew install mongodb-community@3.2`, Then `brew services run mongodb-community@3.2` returned

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.2/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@3.2.plist` exited with 5.
```

And `brew services` shows

```
Name                  Status  User     Plist
mongodb-community@3.2 error   SoftTimur /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.2/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@3.2.plist
nginx                 stopped
```

Could anyone help?